# JSF and rotated components? (Specifically, buttons)

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I'm trying to implement in jsf something that will serve sort of a 3 way pick list:
[image]

I can do this pretty easily.
My only problem is making the buttons rotate as they are in the image.

Is it even possible? (Other than doing some clickable image that will only appear rotated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but the solution is not JSF-related. You should be able to do it with javascript. [Pick one rotation plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/rotation) for jQuery and try using it. The only thing that you have to take in mind is the ID if the controls. Perhaps you won't be able to specify it, so either use the generated one, or use a more complex jQuery selector.